# What is the difference between 'colorBackground' and 'colorSurface'

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

'Sup, everyone!

I'm trying to set up my app theme according to the M3 [color system](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Color.md). And I'm trying to figure out what is the difference between the `android:colorBackground` and `colorSurface`.

Can someone help with this? Because as for now I suppose that the first one is just a legacy attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are making a list with cards and some items on it - `colorBackground` is for list, `colorSurface` is for cards. e.g. background is solid black and cards are dark gray, bounds more visible

note that there is also `inverseSurface` colors, e.g. for selection (long press on list items)

Comment: Thanks, sounds reasonable. Any docs to this explanation?

Comment: [The Material 3 Color Section](https://m3.material.io/styles/color/overview) is probably a good starting point.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I've read the docs already but didn't find the explanation to my question